# Django: What is wrong with this simple code to make user session validation. No errors in Visual Studio Code. Code in body section not work properly

Tags: html, django

I'm new here.
Before asking the question, I tried to search.
I have become convinced that it should work, and it is not.

It works:

```
<a href= "{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</a>
<a href= "{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Login</a>
```

It is not:

```
{% if user.is_autenticated %}
        <p>Hello  {{ user.username }}</p>
        <a href= "{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</a>
{% else %}
        <a href= "{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

I am a beginner, so sorry experienced colleagues. :)
Does anyone have an idea why?

In the browser, you can always see only the login button, even after logging in.

The login procedure works correctly because without logging in you cannot manipulate the data.

Br
Marek

Comment: Its a typo: the h is missing in is_authenticated

Comment: :) Thank you. Everything is ok :)